# Cannot be resolved to a variable eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

The code is supposed to read in a line of text from a textfile and process it, add it to an array of processed lines, and return the array

However I keep getting an error when I try to return the array. I assume I've done something wrong in the body of the code

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName){
        try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        System.out.println("Reading metadata file: "+fileName);

        int len=new Integer(br.readLine()); //read number of entries in file

        //read line in text file
        //process line using createMedia
        //add media to array of media objects

        Media media = createMedia(br.readLine());
        Media[] newMedia = new Media[len];

        for(int i = 0;i<=len;i++){
            newMedia[i] = media;
        }
        //return newMedia
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IO error reading "+fileName);

    }
    return newMedia;
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace. It's pointless to complain about an error message without including said message.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is the array you are trying to return is within try-catch block and it is not accessible outside to the return keyword.

Try this updates:

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName){
    Media[] newMedia = null;//move it here
    ...
    Media media = createMedia(br.readLine());
    newMedia = new Media[len];//note this line 
    ...
    return newMedia;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate thing that stands out to me is the fact that your return variable is declared inside the body of a try.  If an IOException is thrown before the variable gets created (very likely since all the IO is above it), there will be no newMedia to return.

Move the declaration of newMedia out of the try, and initialize it in the try and in the catch.

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName){
    Media[] newMedia;
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        System.out.println("Reading metadata file: "+fileName);

        int len=new Integer(br.readLine()); //read number of entries in file

        //read line in text file
        //process line using createMedia
        //add media to array of media objects

        Media media = createMedia(br.readLine());
        newMedia = new Media[len];

        for(int i = 0;i<=len;i++){
            newMedia[i] = media;
        }
        //return newMedia
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IO error reading "+fileName);
        newMedia = null;
    }
    return newMedia;
}
```